# Detecting reboot programmatically in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, background-process

I have a WP 8.1 Runtime which launches a `DeviceUseTrigger` background task. The problem is that whenever the phone reboots, this task obviously cancels, but the task registration remains in place. So when I launch my app the next time the background task *appears* to be running when in reality it isn't. I want some way of detecting whenever the phone reboots and/or detect in some way whether or not the task is actually running or not. The code I'm using to check background task registration is as follows:

```
foreach(IBackgroundTaskRegistration task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.Values)
        {
            if ((task as BackgroundTaskRegistration).Name == myTaskName)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Task is already running");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the problem in an almost embarrassingly simple way. The background task cancels when the phone is shutting down so I attached an event handler to the `taskInstane.Canceled` event in my background task and just added two lines to it:

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("TaskCancelling.txt" CreateCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
deferral.Complete();
```

Then, in the foreground app, the following code runs whenever the app launches:

```
foreach(IBackgroundTaskRegistration task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.Values)
{
   if ((task as BackgroundTaskRegistration).Name == myTaskName)
   {
      if (await IsFilePresentInLocalDirectory("TaskCancelling.txt"))
      {
         //Task registration is present, but task isn't actually running.
         //Unregister the useless task
         (task as BackgroundTaskRegistration).Unregister(true);
         //Delete the file
         StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("TaskCancelling.txt");
         await file.DeleteAsync();
         //Relaunch the DeviceUseTrigger task
         RelaunchBackgroundTask();
      }
   }
}

private async Task<bool> IsFilePresentInLocalDirectory(string fileName)
{
   try
   {
      StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
      return true;
   }
   catch (Exception exc)
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Pretty self-explanatory, I just create an empty text file to create a sort of log of task cancellation and each time my app launches I check to see it the file is present. If it is, the task is relaunched and the file is deleted.

Comment: There probably should be 'await' when you create the file in cancelling event. Without it technically deferral may be completed earilier than file creation, probably it won't happen, but just in case.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I was typing the code from memory since the project isn't with me. Anyway, corrected.

Comment: Also I think that it would be better to use a special variable in *LocalSettings* rather than creating a file. Access to settings is faster and is a synchronous operation.