# Detect when device Rebooting or Starting in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, background-process, windows-store

I need detect rebooting or device starting, to do this I followed this topic ([Detecting reboot programmatically in Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717798/detecting-reboot-programmatically-in-windows-phone-8-1)), but in my case the method canceled is never called in background task.

When I starting debug, my method is called after forcing changes in timezone that made by:

```
builder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.TimeZoneChange, false));
```

My background task is:

```
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            BackgroundTaskDeferral defferal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
            taskInstance.Canceled += TaskInstance_Canceled;
            defferal.Complete();
        }

        private async void TaskInstance_Canceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
        {
            BackgroundTaskDeferral defferal = sender.GetDeferral();
            try
            {
                StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("bruno.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Fail to create File test: " + e);
            }

            defferal.Complete();
        }
```

I know that is never called, because the next routine is always in false (it works when app is starting MainPage method):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using some hours in this problem, I found the solution, Windows Phone have a System Trigger type that is called when device is booted, named: SessionConnected.

Thus, only need simple changes:

builder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.SessionConnected, false));